# Event management and custom newsletter in Wordpress

Tags: php, events, joomla, wordpress

I have a Joomla 1.5.26 website in which I publish events and conferences dictated by a company. Those are handled by categories (cities).

Until now, I follow this workflow:

- Publish the event (by entering a new registry) or duplicating an
  entry (if apply) with a component called Simple Calendar. It creates
  in the frontend a page for each event and handle those by categories.
- Then, because of the customization of my template, I have to publish an article in the front page with all the information of the current events. Double work.
- Last: Go to a system (based in php and connected to my joomla database) that I created to manage the newsletter. I have to write again all the information of the events in a TinyMCE field and then choose in a select box the group of users, by state (I override the jos_user database and added "State" field. I also override the registration page, so users can select their state of origin).

In that system, I also create a page that let me send a newsletter to **all** the users in jos_user.

**What I need:**

I need to simplify this Workflow. I want to continue using a CMS (I'm thinking in Wordpress).

I need to migrate all the users registered in Joomla (with it custom field).

I will like to publish the events one time, and have the possibility to send a newsletter of upcoming events or category upcoming events to a specific group of user or to all of them.

**What I have tried:**

Wordpress + Event Espresso: this solution didn't work for me, cause' it didn't allow me to handle the newsletter as I need.

**What I don't need:**

- A payment system.
- Attendee Manager.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try out [***this plugin***](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/events-manager/) which I have been working for a long time. It's a good plugin to get the work done.

Comment: I have downloaded and tested it. It does the work of publiching events, but don't handle the newsletter system.